# Show another website in iFrame

Tags: iframe

I am trying to show a website on iFrame tag, it is working fine only at the landing page and while clicking on any page links it redirects me to the live website. I don't want it to redirect it to the live website. I am using the following code in php.

```
<iframe src="demo1.php" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<?php 
    $site = array('http://anusha.bluethink.in/b4bstaging/','http://anusha.bluethink.in/b4bstaging/personalised-balls.html');  
    $i=0;

    foreach($site  as $n) {
        echo file_get_contents($site[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
?>
```